# How to access the Form Control Combobox on a Chart Sheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am trying to build an interactive Chart in excel, what my problem is that i have included an Form Control Combo Box in my chart but I am not able to get the name of that combobox so that i can access that in my VBA code. I have attached an screenshot of the chart.[image]

What i want to know is that what code i can use to access the selected value of this combobox in the screenshot.

I have already tried to record a Macro, but it doesn't record anything related to the Form Control here.

Comment: can't you simply select that combobox on the screen and read its name on the up-left textbox?

Comment: I just had a look at that..it says Drop Down 1. But I am not sure how can I use that name in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the name it's not a ComboBox but a DropDown control

you can refer to it via `Shapes` collection by its name and then by its `ControlFormat` property that returns the [`ControlFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841173(v=office.15).aspx) object, of which you can use properties and methods

```
With Worksheets("MySheet").Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat '<--| change "MySheet" with your actual worksheet name
    MsgBox .ListFillRange
    MsgBox .LinkedCell
    MsgBox .Value
    MsgBox .List(.Value)
End With
```

Comment: @Mohit, did you get through it?

Comment: Yes this is the right way to do , just instead of Worksheets i had to use Charts as I am using these controls on Chart Tab instead of a worksheet. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Hrm... my suggestion would be to RECORD a macro wherein you change the value manually. Then STOP the macro, and go look at the code to find the name of that specific item.

Comment: No I tried that before asking the question, but it doesn't record the changes made in ComboBox. :(

Comment: to prevent this, it's typically good practice to say what you already tried. Please update your question with all the things you tried, and then you might get a meaningful answer.

Comment: I have updated my question now. Suggest if you have any solution for this.